# MariaDB: Performance monitoring

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, monitoring, heidisql

I would like to monitor the performance (duration) of distinct queries. An easy way to do that is to look at the output of HeidiSQL. For example, this simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.patient;
```

gives me the following output on the HeidiSQL-GUI:

```
/* Betroffene Zeilen: 0  Gefundene Zeilen: 1  Warnungen: 0  
                                                        Dauer von 1 Abfrage: 6.022 Sek. */
```

Getting this output I copy/paste the time (6.022), the number of affected rows (0) and the number of located rows (1) into an excel. 
This I want to do periodically to control over the duration of the queries. If duration get critical I want to analyse which part of the code needs to be changed to get better performance.

Since my sql codes are in various scripts (10 scripts) and contains each 5 to 20 queries doing this manually (retrieving these three figures) is very cumbersome. Also, I have to run each single query allone to get the infos for each single query. If I run several queries I got only the info for the whole run.

My idea is to retrieve the infos from a log file with a script (e.g. Perl, Python). But there are the following problems:

1. I could not find a log file containing the same infos as HeidiSQL produces (affected and located number of rows and duration). For example, the log file WS20104444-2.log (general log) does only show queries but no time and other informations. From where can I get the same information from MariaDB as HeidiSQL does?
2. Since I want these informations for each single query but do not want run each single query alone I supposedly have to add a query which does produce these infos:

   ```
   SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'path\log.txt' 
   FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table);

   UPDATE table SET var = 1 WHERE x = 'a';
   -- (1) query which retrieves affected and 
          located number of rows and time and stores in a log.txt
   INSERT INT table SELECT * FROM stage;
   -- (1) query which retrieves affected and 
          located number of rows and time and stores in a log.txt
   ```

   Is there something like (1)?

I'm working with 10.2.11-MariaDB on a Windows 7 (soon Win 10).

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: *"I would like to monitor the performance (duration) of distinct queries. An easy way to do that is to look at the output of HeidiSQL"* MariaDB supports [Slow Query Log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/slow-query-log-overview/) ..  i would suggest to check it out.

Comment: @Raymond It seems to look fine. I succeed to produce the file (`SET`) but it does not collect the infos when I run a query. So, I have to see what is going on. However, thanks for the suggestions, I think it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

(This does not answer the Question asked, but addresses the "real" question.)

The slowlog, with `long_query_time` set to 1.0 (or less) is an excellent tool.  Then use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the data.  It will, by default, list the "worst" query first.